# Running sk-learn model.predict with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i have a scikit-learn created model, a huge test dataset to predict. Now to speed up the prediction i want to implement multiprocessing, but really unable to crack it and need help in this regard.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.externals import joblib
dataset = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')  # 8mln rows
feature_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

#load model
model = joblib.load(model_saved_path)                # random-forest classifier

#predict Function
def predict_func(model, data, feature_cols):
    return model.predict(data[fetaure_cols])

#Normal Execution
predict_vals = predict_func(model, dataset, feature_cols) #130 secs
```

Now I want to use multiprocessing to predict, (chunk the datset and run predict function on each chunk separately in each core, then join back the result).

But not able to do so.

I have tried

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(3) #I think it starts 3 processes
    p.map(predict_func, testData) #How to pass parameters
mp_handler()
```

I have no idea if this is way to do multiprocessing in python(forgive my ignorance here). I have read few search results and came up with this.

If somebody can help in coding, that will be a great help, or a link for read up on multiprocessing will be fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/). And also check your classifier/regressor if it's not already parallelized for this (shown code incomplete to decide on this)!

Comment: @sascha- Above is what i have wrote till now, if you have any sample-reference for "also check your classifier/regressor if it's not already parallelized for this",  plz post the link. Thanks.

Comment: No. Probably you should post more information. And your comment adds nothing new. Yes, you wrote that and it does not work. I just mentioned an abstraction-layer which is the core of all sklearn-parallelizations (in terms of this kind of parallelization; ignoring SIMD or OpenMP).

Comment: information like??

Comment: Reread my first comment.

Comment: Again answer of mine for this, loops back to my first comment.Thanks. I have already used joblib to load the model, does it make my classifier prallelized ? Well I don't know.... I have started machine learning recently and not as smart as you. So better explain or let other help me out. You are making me more and more confused here.

Comment: Well... you don't want to tell us which algorithm you are using... okay... let's guess for you: i'm guessing you are using something which is fully parallelized (for a single prediction). This means, that any other outer parallelization will slow things down. My assumption is wrong? Gosh... how should i know.

Comment: joblib to load is just deserialization (more efficient pickle load) and has nothing to with parallelization per se. joblib, in terms of a library though, can be used for serialization and parallelization (just read the docs).

Comment: Ok, this is now a feedback with clarity. I have used random-forest classifier, and after model.fit(training_data[feature_cols]), i saved it via joblib.dump(model, model_save_dir). I have no idea what is a "fully parallelized Algorithm/Model".Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a [RandomForest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) (which i would have guessed because of slow prediction).

The takeaway message here is: **it's already parallelized (ensemble-level!)!** and all your attempts to do it on the outer-level will slow things down!

It's kind of arbitrary how i interpret these levels, but what i mean is:

- lowest-level: the core-algorithm is parallel

  - Decision-tree is the core of RF; not parallel (in sklearn)!
  - affects single-prediction performance
- medium-level: the ensemble-algorithm is parallel

  - RF = multiple Decision-trees: parallel (in sklearn)!
  - affects single-prediction performance
- high-level: the batch-prediction is parallel

  - This is what you want to do and only makes sense if the lower levels do not exploit your capacities already!
  - does **not** affect single-prediction performance (as you know already)

The general rule is:

- if using the correct arguments (e.g. `n_jobs=-1`; not default!):

  - RF will use `min(number of cores, n_estimators)` cores!

    - Speedup *can* only be achieved, if the above is lower than your number of cores!

So you should use the right `n_jobs` argument at training-time to use parallelization. sklearn will use this as explained and it can be seen [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L581).

If you already trained your classifier with `n_jobs=1` (not parallel), things get more difficult. It *might work out* to do:

```
# untested
model = joblib.load(model_saved_path)
#model.n_jobs = -1                     # unclear if -1 is substituted earlier
model.n_jobs = 4                       # more explicit usage
```

Keep in mind, that using `n_jobs > 1` uses more memory!

Take your favorite OS-monitor, make sure you setup your classifier correctly (parallel -> n_jobs) and observe the CPU-usage during raw prediction. This is not for evaluating the effect of parallelization, but for some indication it is using parallelization!

If you still need parallelization, e.g. when having 32 cores and using `n_estimators=10`, then use [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/), the multiprocessing-wrapper by sklearn-people used a lot within sklearn. The basic examples should be ready to use!

If this will speed things up will depend on many many things (IO and co).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @sascha, i have tried various combination of n_jobs and understood your points clearly(has lot to learn on Machine Learning). Thanks Again :).